# Chrome extension: popup to manipulate textboxes on a website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a Chrome extension based on an extension popup. The popup contains two buttons. Clicking the buttons should paste address data into textboxes on a website. Unfortunately I am unable to get the corresponding textboxes filled, probably because the textboxes on the website can not be accessed through the extension popup.

I read about a contentscript.js that might help - As I'm not experienced well in JavaScript and Chrome extensions, I couldn't get how to implement the contentscript.js within the extension. Any help to make me find a way so solve my problem is appreciated.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Paste Address",
    "version": "2.0",
    "author": "STM",
    "description": "Paste Address",
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "icons": {"16": "btn_edit.png", "48": "btn_edit.png", "128": "btn_edit.png"},
    "browser_action": {"default_icon": "btn_edit.png", "default_popup": "popup.html"}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/options_popup.css" />
    </head>
<body>          
        <section> 
            <button id="address1">Address1</button>
        </section>
        <section> 
            <button id="address2">Address2</button>
        </section>
        <script src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function address1() {
    alert("address1");
    document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["firstname"].value = "firstname1";
    document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["lastname"].value = "lastname1";
    document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["street"].value = "street1";
}

function address2() {
    alert("address2");
    document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["firstname"].value = "firstname2";
    document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["lastname"].value = "lastname2";
    document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["street"].value = "street2";
}

button_click = document.querySelector('#address1').addEventListener('click',function() {address1();}, false);
button_click = document.querySelector('#address2').addEventListener('click',function() {address2();}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

It will explain *why* you need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Your popup is an HTML page; as such, `document` within it refers to itself. You cannot "find" elements from the open tab in it.

First off, you need permissions to access the page. Thankfully, [`"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) is exactly what you need.

Then, you can execute scripts in the currently open tab by using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), also called "programmatic injection".

It's best to make a separate `.js` file for your content script and execute that.

So, for instance:

```
// Make this a separate file address1.js
document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["firstname"].value = "firstname1";
document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["lastname"].value = "lastname1";
document.forms["ModalBoxAddress_form"].elements["street"].value = "street1";
```

And your popup.js:

```
function address1() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "address1.js"});
}

document.querySelector('#address1').addEventListener('click', address1);
```

Same with your second address.

Note that your content script now executes in a separate context and can't access data from your `popup.js` directly. If you need to pass some data, [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) or [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) will help. *But, as they say, that's another story.*